# What is the probability of at least one of a sum of normally distributed variables being greater than a threshold?

Tags: normal-distribution, quality-control

Let's say I have a pencil factory. I don't mind if my pencils are too short, but it's important they're not too long.

My Quality Control department measure each pencil, and their measurement will be normally distributed around the true value for each with a known constant standard deviation *μ*.

But, for each batch of N pencils they only report the **sum** of the lengths in that batch (*S*)

What's the probability of **any** pencil in a batch being above the acceptable length *L*?

Comment: Rephrasing, letting $\theta_i$ be the length of pencil $i$: "$X_1, \dots, X_N$ are iid $N(\theta_i, \sigma^2)$. We observe $Y := \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \sim N(\sum_i \theta_i, N \sigma^2)$. What is the probability that $\max_i \theta_i > L$?" – Sorry, I'm refusing on principle to call a standard deviation $\mu$. :)

Comment: With no assumptions on $\theta_i$, this is impossible to answer; consider $\theta_1 = Y, \theta_2 = 10^{10}, \theta_i = -10^{10} / (N - 2)$, whose observation has maximal likelihood. Obviously pencils can't have negative lengths, but I hope this helps illustrate that without some probability model for $\theta$, your probability question is not well-defined.

Comment: Tell your Quality Control dept. it's probably better to use $\sigma$ for a s.d and $\mu$ for a mean, or people will get confused.